# AngularJS ng-grid - Dynamically updating the columns and results

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-scope, ng-grid

I am newbie in ng-grid. How do we dynamically update the columns and results inside the grid.

I have created a http://plnkr.co/edit/CwUVIzSKVNCMTgpOW87f?p=preview

**Script**

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']); app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}]
    };

    $scope.update_columns = function($event){ console.log("asd")
      $scope.myData = [{new_name: "Moroni", new_age: 50, pin: 123},
       {new_name: "Tiancum", new_age: 43, pin: 345},
       {new_name: "Jacob", new_age: 27, pin: 567},
       {new_name: "Nephi", new_age: 29, pin: 789},
       {new_name: "Enos", new_age: 34, pin: 012}
      ];

      $scope.gridOptions.columnDefs = [
        {field: 'new_name', displayName: 'New Name'}, 
        {field:'new_age', displayName:'New Age'},
        {field:'pin', displayName:'Pin'}
      ];

    } });
```

On page load, the grid will display a set of result and on clicking the change columns, we need to update the results and columns. The way I have implemented right now is not working as expected. Am i doing something  wrong?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 17, accepted):

You must set up your column definition variations on the scope.  You can also define the configuration property `columnDefs` with a string that represents a scope property.  Like the configuration of `data`, this allows you to watch the scope field and switch it out.

[Here is an updated Plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/2Kce2v?p=preview).

Changes to the js:

```
var app = angular.module('myApp', ['ngGrid']);
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
    $scope.columns1 = [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}];
    $scope.columns2 = [{field: 'new_name', displayName: 'New Name'}, {field:'new_age', displayName:'New Age'},{field:'pin', displayName:'Pin'}];
    $scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns1;
    $scope.myData = [{name: "Moroni", age: 50},
                     {name: "Tiancum", age: 43},
                     {name: "Jacob", age: 27},
                     {name: "Nephi", age: 29},
                     {name: "Enos", age: 34}];  
    $scope.gridOptions = { 
        data: 'myData',
        columnDefs: 'columnsSelected'
    };

    $scope.update_columns = function($event) { 

      $scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns2;

      $scope.myData = [{new_name: "Moroni", new_age: 50, pin: 123},
       {new_name: "Tiancum", new_age: 43, pin: 345},
       {new_name: "Jacob", new_age: 27, pin: 567},
       {new_name: "Nephi", new_age: 29, pin: 789},
       {new_name: "Enos", new_age: 34, pin: 012}
      ];
    }
});
```

Comment: Stumbled across the same issue. this works like a charm! Thanks !

Answer (score 1):

You can actually use the same data set since Angular ignores columns that aren't defined in the columnDefs / columnsSelected:

```
app.controller('MyCtrl', function($scope) {
$scope.columns = [];
$scope.columns[true] = [{field: 'name', displayName: 'Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'Age'}];
$scope.columns[false] = [{field: 'name', displayName: 'New Name'}, {field:'age', displayName:'New Age'},{field:'pin', displayName:'Pin'}];
$scope.displayFlag = true;
$scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns[$scope.displayFlag];
  $scope.myData = [
   {name: "Moroni", age: 50, pin: 123},
   {name: "Tiancum", age: 43, pin: 345},
   {name: "Jacob", age: 27, pin: 567},
   {name: "Nephi", age: 29, pin: 789},
   {name: "Enos", age: 34, pin: 012}
  ]; 
$scope.gridOptions = { 
    data: 'myData',
    columnDefs: 'columnsSelected'
};

$scope.update_columns = function($event) { 
  $scope.displayFlag = !$scope.displayFlag;
  $scope.columnsSelected = $scope.columns[$scope.displayFlag];
}
```

});

http://plnkr.co/edit/y5PXl78h653VCWtIMers?p=preview