# AngularJS multifunctional table - where to start

Tags: angularjs, gridview, tabular

I am new with AngularJS and I would like to learn more about it. I was able to use `JBoss Forge2` to create a `Java EE` project with `AngularJS` front-end. However it creates a very basic, non-intuitive GUI (how could it not).

What I would like to do, is to create (or find) a table in which I can display a collection of data.

The table should have:

- a dynamic number of columns (equal to the number of attributes in the
  object of which I would like to display a list)
- sortable on each column
- search filter on each column
- paging option

Where should I start looking, or does such a table already exist? I do understand a little AngularJS already.

Comment: Where to start questions are generally better handled on irc or other instant group communication. http://webchat.freenode.net/?channels=angularjs&uio=d4 for Angular

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Look into [Angular UI Grid](http://ui-grid.info/) which is still under development but usable in its current form.

The grid has a multitude of features which you will find useful, Including:

- [Sorting](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/102_sorting)
- [Pagination](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/214_pagination)
- [Filtering](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/103_filtering)
- [Dynamic Column Updates](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/20419777/angularjs-ng-grid-dynamically-updating-the-columns-and-results)
- User interaction
- [Expandable rows](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/306_expandable_grid)
- [Column Pinning](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/203_pinning)
- [Grouping](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/209_grouping)
- [Edit in place](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/201_editable)
- [Support for Large datasets](http://ui-grid.info/docs/#/tutorial/190_large_dataset)

Plus many more...

Here's an example of a grid using Angular UI-Grid

```js
var app = angular.module('app', ['ngTouch', 'ui.grid']);

app.controller('MainCtrl', ['$scope', function ($scope) {

  $scope.myData = [
    {
        "firstName": "Cox",
        "lastName": "Carney",
        "company": "Enormo",
        "employed": true
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Lorraine",
        "lastName": "Wise",
        "company": "Comveyer",
        "employed": false
    },
    {
        "firstName": "Nancy",
        "lastName": "Waters",
        "company": "Fuelton",
        "employed": false
    }
];
}]);
```

```html
<html ng-app="app">
  <head>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-touch.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/angularjs/1.2.26/angular-animate.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/csv.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/pdfmake.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/docs/grunt-scripts/vfs_fonts.js"></script>
    <script src="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.js"></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="http://ui-grid.info/release/ui-grid-unstable.css" type="text/css">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css" type="text/css">
  </head>
  <body>

<div ng-controller="MainCtrl">
  <div id="grid1" ui-grid="{ data: myData }" class="grid"></div>
</div>


    <script src="app.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Thank you for your extensive example. I am going to study it, as well as the links. I need a little bit of time for that. :) Will respond asap.